# Multiple Knapsack/Bin-packing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, knapsack-problem, np, bin-packing

The problem is the following:

You have a stack with n objects, each with volume Vi. You also have k boxes, all with a fixed volume V. For each object on the top of the stack, if the object fits in the current box, you have to choose between putting it into the box and moving on to the next object, or closing this box and skipping to the next box.

The cost for each box is defined as the volume left in the box squared.

Your goal is to fit all objects into the boxes, and minimize the sum of all boxes cost.

What algorithm should I use (I'm thinking something with graphs)?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving

Comment: @yalpsideman Unlikely to have a solution, since this problem is a rather constrained version: the order of considering objects is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by dynamic programming.

The state can be (number of full boxes, number of objects taken).

The function is the minimum total cost of achieving such a state.

The transitions can be made as follows.
Let us start at state `(box, obj)`, when we already know the best way to achieve  it costs `f[box][obj]`.
Take the objects number `obj+1`, `obj+2`, `...`, until the sum of their volumes `v[i]` exceeds the box capacity `V`.

After taking each new object `i`, what happens if we close the current box?
We have achieved state `(box + 1, i)`, and the cost is `f[box][obj]` plus the square of (V minus the sum of the volumes `v[obj+1]`, `v[obj+2]`, `...`, `v[i]`).
If it is the best way so far to achieve state the `(box+1, i)`, assign it to `f[box+1][i]`.

The base is `f[0][0] = 0`.

The answer is `f[k][n]`, where `k` is the number of boxes and `n` is the number of objects.

In pseudocode:

```
f = array [0..k] [0..n] of integers
fill f[][] with infinity
f[0][0] = 0
for box = 0, 1, ..., k-1:
    for obj = 0, 1, ..., n:
        if f[box][obj] < infinity:
            left = V
            f[box+1][obj] = min (f[box+1][obj], f[box][obj] + V*V)
            for i = obj+1, obj+2, ..., n:
                left -= v[i]
                if left < 0:
                    break
                f[box+1][i] = min (f[box+1][i], f[box][obj] + left*left)
answer = f[k][n]
```

Comment: Your answer is really good, but I think I didn't express the problem well enough... I forgot to mention that empty boxes are also taken into account on the final cost. Example: 2 objects of volume 5, and 2 boxes of volume 10, the least cost possible is 50, by distributing one object per box. Do you think we can adapt your algorithm?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the part where the number of boxes is a fixed integer `K`. Then the answer is just `f[K][n]`. And we have to add a transition corresponding to an empty box, that's one added line before the inner `i` loop. I'll edit the code in an hour or two.

Comment: @leodaher Edited the answer to use exactly `k` boxes.